Segmentation fault for inserting into an BST
So for this class here, I have to write out functions, including a recursive find function, an insert function, and a operator[] function, which overall helps insert into a BST
#include <compare>
#include <cstddef>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>


template<typename Key, typename Value>
struct BST
{
  using KeyValue_Pair = std::pair<Key const, Value>;

  struct Node
  {
    Node() = default;
    Node( KeyValue_Pair const & pair ) : _pair{ pair } {}

    KeyValue_Pair _pair = { Key{}, Value{} };

    Node * _left   = nullptr;
    Node * _right  = nullptr;
    Node * _parent = nullptr;
  };

  Node *      _root = nullptr;
  std::size_t _size = 0;


Node * find( Key const & key )
 {
   return find(key, _root);  // Delegate the call to the private helper function
 }

Node* find(Key const& key, Node* current) {
    // Base Case: Node not found
    if (current == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    // Visit: Node found
    if (key == current->_pair.first) {
        return current;
    }

    // Recurse: Search left or right subtree
    if (key < current->_pair.first) {
        return find(key, current->_left);
    } else {
        return find(key, current->_right);
    }
}

Node * insert( KeyValue_Pair const & pair ) {
     Node * newNode = new Node( pair );
     if(_root == nullptr){
      _root = newNode;
      ++_size;
      return newNode;
    }
    Node * current = _root;
    Node * parent  = nullptr;

    while(current != nullptr){
      parent = current;
      auto comp   = std::compare_weak_order_fallback( pair.first, current->_pair.first );
      if( comp == 0 ) return current;
      else if(comp < 0 ) current = current->_left;
      current = current->_right;
    }
    auto comp = std::compare_weak_order_fallback( pair.first, current->_pair.first );
    if( comp < 0 ) parent->_left = newNode;
    else parent->_right = newNode;

    newNode->_parent = parent;
    ++_size;
    return newNode;
}

Value & operator[]( Key const & key )
{
  return insert( { key, Value{} } )->_pair.second;
}   

//everything under this comment already came with the code
void print()
{
  auto count = 0uz;
  print( _root, count );
}

void print( Node * current, std::size_t & count )  // in-order traversal
{
  // Base case
  if( current == nullptr ) return;

  // Recurse left
  print( current->_left, count );

  // Visit
  auto && [key, value] = current->_pair;
  std::cout << std::format( "{:3}:  {{{}, {}}}\n", ++count, key, value );

  // Recurse right
  print( current->_right, count );
}

~BST() noexcept
{ clear(); }
};

int main()
{
  BST<unsigned int, std::string> myTree;

  std::cout << "Test Case 1:\n";                     //          50         //
  myTree[50] = "indeed";                             //        /   \        //
  myTree.insert( { 40, "Structures" } );             //       40    60      //
  myTree.insert( { 60, "very" } );                   //      / \   / \      //
  myTree.insert( { 30, "Lego" } );                   //     30 45 55  70    //
  myTree.insert( { 45, "are" } );
  myTree[55] = "truly";
  myTree[70] = "entertaining";
  myTree.print();
  std::cout << "------------------------------\n";
}


yet, I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error message for test case 1. I'm not sure if the error is in the recursive find or insert function. I would greatly appreciate some feedback, please and thank you. I also apologize if the code is too long, I wanted to include the test case 1 from main but I wasn't sure if I should include the void print functions or not.

You ran it under Valgrind right?    https://valgrind.org/

I don't know what valgrind is so no. I'm relatively new to programming so I apologize\

The while loop in the insert function is missing an else, so it never follows the left branch.

I see. Thank you. Is that the only thing of the ordinary though?

Also, you do while(current != nullptr), but right below the loop you dereference current, which will be null at that point.

I see that now. Thank you.

Your while loop either exits when it finds a match or when it runs out of the bottom -- at which point current is null. The very next statement dereferences current. You maybe mean parent. Is this the output you expect:
  1:  {30, Lego}
  2:  {40, Structures}
  3:  {45, are}
  4:  {50, indeed}
  5:  {55, truly}
  6:  {60, very}
  7:  {70, entertaining}

That's what I got when I made two changes:
cout << "while....\n";
    while(current != nullptr){
      parent = current;
      auto comp   = std::compare_weak_order_fallback( pair.first, current->_pair.first );
      if( comp == 0 ) return current;
      else if(comp < 0 ) current = current->_left;
      else current = current->_right;
    }
cout << "while done\n";
    auto comp = std::compare_weak_order_fallback( pair.first, parent->_pair.first );

See the else-clause at the end of the while loop (you were just setting it) and the dereference of parent instead of current.

Tbh, I'm exactly sure what the ouput is supposed to look like. Unfortunately I don't have a sample output, yet, i'm guessing that it would look something like that yes
